# Dependencia JAX-RS (com.sun.xml.ws) não empacotar arquivos tipo zip

Tags: java, maven

Olá.
O projeto possui essa dependência.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

No momento de empacotar tudo esses arquivos vão juntos (não lembro perfeitamente o nome):
samples2.3.3.zip e release-documentation2.3.3.zip

Existe uma regra tola no cliente, um script do Jenkis que não permite arquivos zip que contenha pasta.

Gostaria de remover esses arquivos do empacotamento.
Já tentei esse código mas não funcionou:

```
  <id>distribution</id>
  ...
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>*.zip</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
```

E até abaixo de cada tag outputDirectory coloquei uma exclusão de zip. Também não funcionou. Alguém já precisou fazer isso? Não empacotar certos arquivos de uma dependencia?

```
  <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>*.zip</exclude>
  </excludes>
```

Answer (score -3):

Descobri como fazer.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
     <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.3</version>
     <type>pom</type>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>samples</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>release-documentation</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>            
</dependency>
```

Este post em inglês me ajudou.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119055/excluding-maven-dependencies

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]